# how can call a html page div from javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am working on **phonegap with android**. I am creating a login page. After the login validation I want to jump to the welcome div if the user is authorized .

This is my javascript page:- myjavascrpt.js

```
   var logi=item.id;   
   if(logi>0)
   call welcome div of index.html
    else
    alert("invalid user"); 

                       // in this logi variable i have userid of successful user.
                       // now i want to  
                        // display this id into the div which is exist in my 
                        // html page.
                        // now what should i write here so i can call welcome 
                        // div of html page and i can use 
                        // this value of logi variable.
```

This is my index.html whose welcome div I want to call.

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-url="streaming" id="streaming">
             <h1> do some thing related to streaming</h1>
        </div>  
        **
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-url="welcome" id="welcome">
        <h1> you are welcome</h1>
        </div>
        **
      </body>
    </html>
```

so please tell me what code should I use to call the div of a html page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about *calling a html page div from javascript*, but if you want to **set the content of a DIV via javascript**, it's done that way:

In javascript:

```
var d = document.getElementByID("welcome");
d.innerHTML = logi;
```

But this would override the `<h1> you are welcome</h1>` text. So change that line to be

```
<span id="userwelcome"></span><h1>, you are welcome</h1>
```

and your javascript to

```
var d = document.getElementByID("userwelcome");
d.innerHTML = logi;
```

Comment: `if(logi>0){
   var d = document.getElementByID("userwelcome");
d.innerHTML = logi;}`

Comment: yeah you are right but how can i display the welcome-div of index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple jQuery -

```
if(logi>0) { $('#welcome').html(logi);}
```

Comment: sorry sir i am unable to jump my welcome div of html page by using your code.